# Azure Storage Rest API: CORS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

From an intranet site I need  to post data to Azure storage using REST API(CORS is enabled in Azure side). How can I overcome the CORS issue raised but the browser without changing the browser configuration?

Comment: If the CORS is configured properly at the storage level, then you don't have to do anything on the browser side. My guess is that there's some issue on the CORS settings on the storage side. Can you share more details about the error you're getting?

Comment: use jsonp and please show us your code, so we could tell you more about it

Comment: I can do post from IE 11 but by default chrome or safari doesn't allow me to do that, these browsers throws cross origin issue. Also, JsonP is not supported with Azure.